# ¿como se debe limpiar correctamente un textarea?

Tags: javascript

espero que bien, como dice el titulo tengo esa duda o más que duda,ese problema por que estuve un día entero batallando con este problema.
Quiero que al apretar la tecla enter despues de haber escrito algo me limpie el textarea cosa que lo viene haciendo bien pero cuando no hay nada en el textarea y se apreta enter me genera el div igual al parecer está linea no cubre el caso if(valueComentario.length>0) o tal vez lo hace pero al apretar enter se genera un espacio en blanco lo cual no creo por que aqui le digo que lo deje vacío padre.children[0].value=""; mi pregunta basicamente es si se debe de limpiar así o hay alguna funcion javascript que le haga un reset al textarea o mi otro idea es que si está vacio y se presiona la tecla enter de alguna manera se presione la tecla borrar,gracias por su tiempo :3 PD:el ajax ese no hace nada por ahora la idea es que guarde el comentario en una base de datos le falta todavía[image: le paso foto para que quede mas claro,luego de escribir un comentario y presionar enter apreté las tecla shif + flecha arriba para que seleccione si hay algo y me marca un espacio en blanco como se vé]

```
        function cajaDeComentarios(id){
    let n="a";
    n=n+id.toString();
    let imagen=document.getElementById(id);
    let cajaComentarios=document.createElement("textarea");
    cajaComentarios.setAttribute("id",n);
    cajaComentarios.setAttribute("name","texto");
    cajaComentarios.setAttribute("rows","1");
    cajaComentarios.setAttribute("cols","45");
    cajaComentarios.setAttribute("onkeypress","insertarComentario(event,this.parentNode.id)");
    imagen.appendChild(cajaComentarios);
  }


      function insertarComentario(e,id){

    var padre=document.getElementById(id);
    var valueComentario=padre.children[0].value;
    //crear elemento si existe comentario
    if(valueComentario.length>0){

    if(e.keyCode == 13){


      var objeto= new XMLHttpRequest();

      var usuario='<?php echo $_SESSION['nomUsuario'];?>';
      var informacionDelComentario="usuario="+usuario+"&comentario="+valueComentario;
      objeto.open('POST','/guardarComentario.php',true);

    var comentario=document.createElement("div");
    //crear un nodo de texto
    var texto=document.createTextNode(valueComentario);
    comentario.style.width = "80%";
    comentario.style.marginBottom = "5px";
    comentario.style.color = "black";
    comentario.style.fontFamily = "Patrick Hand";
    comentario.style.fontSize = "17px";

    comentario.appendChild(texto);
    padre.parentNode.appendChild(comentario);
    padre.children[0].value="";

      }

    }

  }
```

Comment: bueno al final lo solucione cambiando de textarea a textbox,con un textbox anda perfecto el código,gracias igualmente

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta te comparto un ejemplo de como vaciar el valor de tu input. Podes ver la documentación del método [event.prevenDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/). De todas maneras tenés otras funcionalidades, quizás necesites refactorizar o debbuguear otra sección de tu código y sería mas claro que subas todo tu ejemplo a un [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/) o [CodePen](https://codepen.io) y nos compartas el link.

**JavaScript:**

```
const textBox = document.getElementById('textBox');
textBox.addEventListener('keypress', eraseTextBoxValue, false);

function eraseTextBoxValue(evt) {
  const charCode = evt.charCode;
  const textBoxValue = textBox.value;
  if(charCode === 13) { textBox('') } ; 
}
```